# Import .webtest file to fiddler?

Tags: fiddler

Is the .webtest file can be imported to fiddler to view the http traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Fiddler exports WebTest files but does not import them. You can, however, use VSTS to run the .WebTest file while Fiddler records the actual traffic issued by VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open VSTS WebTest on the machine which doesn't have VSTS installed you might be interested in [this post](http://www.bugtrap.co.uk/2010/06/visual-studio-web-test-viewer.html).

Thanks,
Maciej